# Ask Question seems broken using Safari on Mac

Tags: bug

I'm using Safari on Mac.

It seems that since the recent SO update a lot in Ask Question seems broken.

**Examples:**

- There are no formatting buttons shown.
- There is no preview shown.
- There is no tag auto-complete (in the screenshot I was aiming for PHP of  course).

[image]

**Update 1**

Web Editor shows:

```
[Error] QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota.
    l (full.en.js, line 3)
    r (full.en.js, line 3)
    (anonymous function) (ask, line 96)
    (anonymous function) (stub.en.js, line 1)
    n (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    (anonymous function) (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    n (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    fire (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    (anonymous function) (stub.en.js, line 1)
    (anonymous function) (stub.en.js, line 1)
    n (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    fire (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    (anonymous function) (stub.en.js, line 1)
    n (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    add (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    t (stub.en.js, line 1)
    n (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    fire (jquery.min.js, line 2)
    onreadystatechange (stub.en.js, line 1)
```

**Update 2**

These problems don't exist whilst editing a question, so it's just the initial creating a question that experiences these problems.

Comment: Looks like you have javascript disabled, or failed to load the external javascript files.

Comment: @Servy (oh, name auto-complete still works) Yes I have this running in a private window. So it's intended behaviour then I guess? What is so different about this website that would cause it to break? I have loads of websites open that work perfectly fine :-(

Comment: Can you check if all domains mentioned in [what else do I need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) are working from your networklocation?

Comment: @rene Yes all domains are accessible. By the way Servy, it seems JavaScript works fine in a private window, so it's not that.

Comment: any errors in the developer console? Assuming that still exist in Safari...

Comment: @rene Yep, I've added it to the question.

Comment: This requires a dev to look into. Not sure why all quota would get consumed.

Comment: @rene Ok, also see my second update (I don't know if it helps).

Comment: There is a [bug report here on MSE from 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123116/safari-5-1-2-log-in-doesnt-work)

Comment: @rene Ok, so is this waiting on someone at SO to fix, or? Will they see this?

Comment: [Read this post of Tim Post while you wait for 6-8 weeks to get if fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247178/158100) ;)